# How to show network/internet strength in Flutter

Tags: flutter, network-connection

I have an app, I need to show the internet connectivity strength in app, such as for mobile network it should show (2g/3g/4g) or for wifi or internet it would show something like strong/medium/low speed. Is there any package to do that? I have seen this internet_speed_test package, but do not know how to implement this according to my need.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this plugin [internet_speed](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test) to get speed of internet and  use these values to show in your UI.

You can also read this page: [Here](https://itnext.io/network-connectivity-in-flutter-15e16c2598f)